# Ubuntu login error although password is correct

Tags: login

So I was trying to install Hadoop and probably made some changes to some files.
Since then when I try to log in to Ubuntu , after entering the password,the screen blinks and comes back to original log in page.

Any help would be welcome. I have tried all suggestions mentioned in questions similar to mine but was unable to solve the problem. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Which files in /etc did you change?  Can you log into a virtual terminal (text only)? Any recent changes to your video driver?

Comment: This was the tutorial I followed and I don't seem to be getting what is wrong.  https://districtdatalabs.silvrback.com/creating-a-hadoop-pseudo-distributed-environment                                                                                                                 
I am able to log in using Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate -- you can login to a text virtual terminal, (the guest session probably works), but your login fails.  Start deleting the "hidden" files in your home directory, starting with .Xauthority until you can login in.  Maybe just rename them so you can bring them back if you need them.  They are basically config files which would get recreated if needed.